# How to understand the difference between 'sort -uk 4n -uk 6n -uk 9n ', 'sort -uk 4 -uk 6 -uk 9' and 'sort -uk 4,4 -uk 6,6 -uk 9,9'?

Tags: bash

I have a huge a mount of data with various column numbers. I want to output those data only with 11 columns and sort them by column 4, 6, and 9. If I use

```
awk NF==11 17144_bondlength.dat |sort -uk 4 -uk 6 -uk 9
```

or

```
awk NV==11 17144_bondlength.dat |sort -uk 4,4 -uk 6,6 -uk 9,9
```

I cannot get what I want. If I use

```
awk NF==11 17144_bondlength.dat |sort -uk 4n -uk 6n -uk 9n
```

I can get what I want. Here, 17144_bondlength.dat is file name.

My question is how to under the three commands? Any further comments would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it `NF` or `NV`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says in the `sort` help, an `n` on a key definition means that it applies that sort order to the key instead of the default or otherwise-specified sort order. `n` means numeric (as opposed to lexicographic).

> My question is how to under the three commands?

The operand to `-k` is KEYDEF. Here's what the help says for it:

> KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position,
>   where F is a field number and C a character position in the field;
>   both are origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.
>   If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted
>   from the beginning of the preceding whitespace.  **OPTS is one or more
>   single-letter ordering options [bdfgiMhnRrV], which override global
>   ordering options for that key.**  If no key is given, use the entire
>   line as the key

*(my emphasis)*

The ordering option `-n` is:

> -n, --numeric-sort
>
> compare according to string numerical value

So that tells us this about those three `sort`s:

> ```
> sort -uk 4 -uk 6 -uk 9
> ```

Sorts with three keys:

- A key starting at column 4 and continuing to end of line (because the end defaults to the end of line)
- A key starting at column 6 and continuing to end of line
- A key starting at column 9 and continuing to end of line

All three use the default sort.

> ```
> sort -uk 4,4 -uk 6,6 -uk 9,9
> ```

Sorts with three keys:

- A key starting at column 4 and ending at column 4
- A key starting at column 6 and ending at column 6
- A key starting at column 9 and ending at column 9

All three use the default sort.

> ```
> sort -uk 4n -uk 6n -uk 9n
> ```

Same as the first one above (with the keys starting at 4, 6, and 9 but continuing through end of line), but using a numeric sort.

If you want to sort on a single character, numerically, you probably wanted `-uk 4,4n` (and the same for 6,6 and 9,9).

Comment: Thank you so much! I read an article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-command-linuxunix-examples/ which puts n behind the key. The help file of sort does not show more examples. So I felt confused. Thanks for your interpretation.